# $(p \rightarrow q) \land (\lnot p\rightarrow q) \equiv q$

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

Prove that $(p \rightarrow q) \land (\lnot p\rightarrow q)$ is logical equivalent to $q$ by using a chain of logical equivalences.

The question states explicitly not to use a truth table.

I tried the following:
$(p \rightarrow q) \land (\lnot p\rightarrow q)\equiv (\lnot p \lor q) \land (p \lor q) $.
Distributing the operators, we obtain:
$(p \rightarrow q) \land (\lnot p\rightarrow q)\equiv q \lor (\lnot p \land q) \lor (p \land q) $.

However, I don’t know how to continue. Please help!

Comment: factor q in the expression to make $p\lor\lnot p$ appear

Comment: Thank you! Brilliant idea! :)